# How to disable inspections of compile error of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

IntelliJ IDEA suggests there is compile error in source code of jetty.

In Eclipse, it does suggest nothing. And i can run this code. So i think this is the problem of IDEA.

My questions is how to disable this??

[image]

Comment: Try to take a look at this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just disable compile errors of source file in intellij. You can just disable inspection of some code patterns or compile warnings.

You can flag the folder not to be a source folder in module configuration, and the file will not be compiled anymore...

(But probably you need to investigate the underlined error to fix it really... maybe there is a conflict or a missing library in project configuration like the defined java Project Language Level)

Comment: I think this is not the error of source code, but the problem of IDEA. This is the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ContextHandler.java)

Comment: Have you already checked the project language level in configuration ?